# Akka-http, getting client IP in Java

Tags: java, akka-http

I have the following basic code to start an akk-http service and I would like to pass the client IP into my route handler.

```
...
final Flow<HttpRequest, HttpResponse, NotUsed> myFlow= myRoute().flow(actorSystem, actorMaterializer);

final CompletionStage<ServerBinding> binding = akkaHttp.bindAndHandle(myFlow,
ConnectHttp.toHost(configurationInstance.getBindAddress(), configurationInstance.getBindPort()), actorMaterializer);
...
```

I found this post:

[Obtaining the client IP in Akka-http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40132262/obtaining-the-client-ip-in-akka-http)

However it uses the low level API.

So far I got this, but I do not want to change to the low level API. Is there a way to get this to work with the high level API? I get a compilation error on the myRoute(), I am not sure how I can create a handler for this approach.

```
    ...
            Http.get(system)
                    .bind(ConnectHttp.toHost(configurationInstance.getBindAddress(),
                        configurationInstance.getBindPort()), mat);

            CompletionStage<ServerBinding> binding =
                     rverSource.runWith(Sink.foreach(connection -> {
                             connection.handleWithAsyncHandler(   
                                myRoute(connection.remoteAddress()), mat); // ERROR   
                })).run(mat);
 ...
 public Route finalRoute(InetSocketAddress client) { .... }
```

--
(UPDATE) This is what worked, after the help from Stefano Bonetti, below.

```
ompletionStage<ServerBinding> binding =
          serverSource.to(Sink.foreach(connection -> {
                  connection.handleWith(MyRoute(connection.remoteAddress())
                  .flow(system, mat), mat);
                }
           )).run(mat);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to convert you `Route` to a `Flow[HttpRequest, HttpResponse, NotUsed]` and pass it to the `handleWith` function.

```
connection.handleWith(myRoute(connection.remoteAddress()).flow(actorSystem, mat), mat);
```

Comment: I tried that, but I get: 

Error:(131, 30) java: method runWith in class akka.stream.javadsl.Source<Out,Mat> cannot be applied to given types;
  required: akka.stream.Graph<akka.stream.SinkShape<akka.http.javadsl.IncomingConnection>,M>,akka.stream.Materializer
  found: akka.stream.javadsl.Sink<java.lang.Object,java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage<akka.Done>>
  reason: cannot infer type-variable(s) M
    (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)

Comment: I did get it to work, your suggestion helped, but I had to make minor changes. I will update the original question with the code.